# Full binary tree theorem proof validity?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, induction, alternative-proof, trees

I'm reviewing some of the theorems that make up the Full binary tree theorem and want to make sure my proof for how the number of internal nodes $I$ is related to the number of total nodes $N$ is correct.

I realize you could relate the number of internal nodes to the number of leaves and them simply add, and go from there but I'm trying not to use that proof in this example.

I'm using induction and I believe my proof valid but something about it seems so simple (and a bit wordy) I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Also if there are any other proofs someone would like to dish out that would be great. I realize you could do this purely with numbers and less "english" if trying to prove this on a perfect binary tree (much tighter restrictions on the tree), however the most concise way I can think of proving this for a full binary tree is rather wordy, and below.

### The total number of nodes $N$ in a tree with $I$ internal nodes is $2I + 1$

#### Base case

A tree with $0$ internal nodes $I$ has $2(0) + 1 = 1$ total nodes.

#### Assumption

Let's assume that any full binary tree with $I$ internal nodes has $2I+1$ total nodes $N$.

#### Inductive step

Given a tree $T$ with $I+1$ internal nodes, take one of it's internal nodes whose
children are both leaves and remove it's children. $T$ now has one less internal node
or $I$ internal nodes meaning it has $2I+1$ total nodes. If we add the children back to
our selected node, the number of internal nodes increases by $1 \text{ from } I \Rightarrow I+1$
and our total number of nodes $N$ increases by $2 \text{ from } 2I+1 \Rightarrow 2I+3$ which is the
same as $2(I+1) + 1 \quad \blacksquare$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went slightly astray with the last sentence: you lost track of the number of internal nodes. If we add the children back in, the number of internal nodes increases by $1$ from $I$ to $I+1$, not from $I+1$ to $I+2$. You also need to show that there actually *is* an internal node whose children are both leaves. If you’ve already defined the height (or depth, depending on your terminology) of a node, you can pick a leaf $v$ whose height is maximal: its sister must also be a leaf. You can also add a little connective tissue to the induction step, something like this:

> Suppose that the result is true for all full binary trees with $I$ internal nodes, and let $T$ be a full binary tree with $I+1$ internal nodes and $N$ nodes altogether. $T$ has at least one internal node, so it must have a leaf; let $v$ be a leaf of maximal height, so that its sister is necessarily also a leaf. Remove $v$ and its sister, and let $T'$ be the resulting tree; the parent of $v$, which was an internal node of $T$, is a leaf of $T'$, and the status of the other nodes of $T'$ is unchanged, so $T'$ has $I$ internal nodes. It is also a full binary tree, so by the induction hypothesis $T'$ has $2I+1$ nodes altogether. Clearly $N=(2I+1)+2=2(I+1)+1$, as desired.

Comment: If I add the case where $I = 1$ to the base cases, is that enough to prove that some internal node with two leaf children does exist, since at least two leaves exist (and obviously they must be parented by one internal node)?

Comment: @DomFarolino: No, because there can be leaves whose sisters are internal.

Comment: Ok, so that is why I need to specify to choose two leaves that are at the maximum depth of the tree then. Thanks

Comment: @DomFarolino: That’s right. You’re welcome.

Comment: Quick question, is the first proof on [this page](http://www.ida.liu.se/opendsa/OpenDSA/Books/TDDD86_2014/html/BinaryTreeFullThm.html) incorrect for your previous reasons? While having the base case $I = 1$ proves some internal node with two leaves does exist, there is no picking leaves based off of height/depth

Comment: @DomFarolino: The extra base case doesn't actually do anything: the argument would be the same without it. And that argument has the same problem as your original argument: it simply takes for granted that there is an internal node whose children are both leaves. Either that was proved earlier, or the argument is slightly defective.

Comment: Gotcha. Still getting used to exactly how many assumptions I am taking for granted etc. I understand your way of doing it thanks

Comment: @DomFarolino: It takes a bit of practice, especially when some of them are intuitively obvious. You're welcome!

Comment: sorry to keep extending this but the more I look at it, assuming a full binary tree has one leaf is the same as assuming it has two (since its full), and assuming a full binary tree has two leaves is the same has assuming a full binary tree HAS an internal mode with two leaves. So the more I think about it we're saying the exact same thing. You're just choosing the children (v and sibling) first and I'm choosing the parent first. But you can't have two children without having a parent that has two children. They are both inextricably connected no?

Comment: @DomFarolino: *Every* internal node has two children, but they aren’t necessarily both leaves: they could be two internal nodes, one internal node and one leaf, or two leaves. The argument doesn’t work unless you pick an internal node whose children are both leaves, so you have to prove that there is such a node. To put it a little differently, every leaf has a sibling, but that sibling could be either a leaf or an internal node.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused because in my argument above in the question I do specify that you need to choose an internal mode whose children are both leaves. So now I have to either prove such a node exists, or instead select two leaves who share the same parent (which I think is what you're proof does), which seems identical as selecting the parent (internal node) who parents both children you selected. Are you saying, even though they are both identical since your way is more explicit it makes the proof valid (because you're starting with the fact that there is guaranteed two leaves)?

Comment: If your version of the proof is right solely due to the explicit nature, I think I can understand that. The only thing I can't get around is that I think they are saying at some high level the exact same thing. An internal node with two leaf children exists if and only if you can select two sibling leaves (with the same parent). Sorry if I'm being dense here :(

Comment: @DomFarolino: I’m saying that although you correctly recognized that you needed an internal node whose children were both leaves, you didn’t actually prove that there *is* one. My proof that there is one focussed on the leaves, but if you want to focus on internal nodes, you can adapt it by letting $v$ be an internal node whose height is maximal, say $h$. Being internal, $v$ must have two children; their height is $h+1$, which is greater than $h$, so they can’t be internal and must therefore be leaves.

Comment: OK so even though you and I can intuitively come to the conclusion that some internal node with two leaves does exist in order to prove that I can and am using that node I need to put some restraints on it (or the leaves) to show the node I am using has certain existential qualities. I think that makes a lot more sense now. In that we need to show the qualities of a node that meets my requirements to prove I can use it

Answer (score 1):

To carry out the inductive step, you need an internal node with two leaves. You might have to prove that such a node exists for $I\geq1$ in a full binary tree. You can avoid that by choosing any internal node except the root and removing the full subtree rooted at it, thereby adding a leaf node to the original tree in its place.

This, however, needs a full tree with a non-root internal node in the inductive step, that is, $I\geq2$, so consideration of $I=1$ must be added as base case.

Comment: Since I need to add $I = 1$ as a base case to show that there exists some internal node (not the root) that has a whole `subtree` rooted at it, does this also imply that there obviously must exist some internal node which parents two leaves? It seems a tad less explicit this way but they seem to mean the same thing to no?

Comment: Whenever you choose something, you have to prove the existence first. Existence of a proper subtree seems less of a requirement than existence of a full 3-node subtree. But, thinking about it, my use of subtrees relies on the fact that trees are connected acyclic graphs, otherwise you'd have to cut more than one edge. And that subtrees of full trees are full as well. For a full 3-node subtree that's more obvious than for an arbitrary-size subtree.

Comment: Ok, makes sense that we need to prove what we decide to choose. It sounds like at the end of your comment you're saying that its easier to prove a full 3-node subtree exists in a full tree with $I \geq 1$ internal nodes than it is to prove a full arbitrary-size subtree exists?

Comment: If part of your definition of a full binary (sub)tree is that every non-root node has degree either 1 or 3, then it is easy to deduce that the subtree is full. This illustrates the need to avoid "easy to see" shortcuts and use definitions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the total nodes in tree $T$, of which $I$ nodes are internal. Since, the root vertex of a binary tree is of degree $2$, $(N-I)$ leaves are of degree $1$ and rest $(I-1)$ vertices of degree $3$, thus by Handshaking theorem, one gets

$\sum_{r=0}^{n}deg(v_r)=2(no. of edges)$

$\implies 2+(N-I)+3(I-1)=2(N-1)$

$\implies N=2I+1$

Comment: The explanation applies only to full binary trees with more than one node, but apart from that, it's a nice proof, like [that one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/208343/75794). Here, we focus on the OP's induction approach however, otherwise [Brian's alternative proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/208336/75794) would apply as well..

Comment: @ccorn...yes I agree